# Is it possible to generate an interactive pdf using puppeteer and Nodejs?

Tags: html, node.js, pdf, puppeteer

I have been trying to create pdf reports of html dashboard pages using puppeteer lib for my NodeJS web application. The thing is that the html have dynamic elements on the page, like buttons that toggle hide/show chartjs' and all. Is it possible to use puppeteer to create an interactive pdf?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to duplicate a dynamic web page (that uses client-side Javascript) in a PDF.  Not really possible in any generic sense of the word.  There are some interactive capabilities in a PDF, but I don't think there's any automatic conversion from HTML/Javascript to interactive PDF.

Comment: PDFs do have javascript (not enabled in all viewers) but I don't know of any way to save it like that. Somebody is probably working on it but I wouldn't expect to see it in chrome.